# which one should I use: os.sep or os.path.sep?

Tags: python, operating-system

They are same, but which one should I use?

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html:

> `os.sep`
>
> > The character used by the operating system to separate pathname components. This is '/' for   POSIX and '\' for Windows. Note that knowing this is not sufficient to be able to parse or concatenate pathnames — use os.path.split() and os.path.join() — but it is occasionally useful. Also available via os.path.

Comment: They are NOT always the same. For instance, on Mac OS X, `os.sep` returns `/`, but `os.pathsep` returns `:`.

Comment: @jvriesem `os.pathsep` is supposed to be different than `os.path.sep` and `os.sep`. See [os.pathsep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pathsep) vs [os.sep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep)

Comment: Just to make this clear to readers who, like me, may have misread the comments by jvriesem and JETM. `os.sep` and `os.path.sep` are consistent in their values on any OS, `os.pathsep` (no dot between path and sep) is something [completely different](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pathsep).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I'd use `os.path.sep` to make it very clear that it's the path separator… But consistency is more important, so if one is already being used, use that. Otherwise, pick one and use it all the time.

**Edit**: Just to make sure you're not reinventing the wheel, though, the `path` module already has `join`, `split`, `dirname`, and `basename` functions… So you should rarely need to use `os.sep`:

```
>>> os.path.join("foo", "bar", "baz")
'foo/bar/baz'
>>> os.path.split(_)
('foo/bar', 'baz')
```

Comment: It seems the doc only documents os.sep, and it seems there are more places using os.sep than os.path.sep. I agree with you that os.path.sep is more clear. Is there any consideration from the original designer's point of view that we don't know?

Comment: That's odd, because `sep` is actually defined in the `path` module (well, specifically, the `${SYSTEM}path` module, where `$SYSTEM` is, eg, `posix`, `nt`, etc), and explicitly imported into `os` (from `os.py`, after the correct os-specfic “os” and “path” modules have been loaded: `from os.path import (…, sep, …)`.

Comment: So, tl;dr: I'm not sure. It would make sense if *all* of the `path` module was imported into `os`… But some parts (ex, `path.join`) aren't.

Comment: zhigang: The documentation you quoted in the question says "Also available via os.path."

Comment: Yeah. I see. Does that mean 'os.sep' is preferred?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't think it matters all that much. I'd prefer `os.path.sep`. The standard library seems to prefer `os.sep` (grepping for it has 65 hits verses 11 hits for `path.sep`). Honestly, if I was reading a code base, the only thing that would annoy me is if the two were used inconsistently.

Comment: as of python 2.7.3. do: `os.path.join(*['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])`

Comment: D'oh! Thanks @Alex, that is correct. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: How do you get ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] with python 2.7.1 and ever since 1995 I've been getting:<br><code>>>> os.path.join("foo", "bar", "baz")<br>
'foo/bar/baz'<br>
>>> os.path.split(_)<br>
('foo/bar', 'baz')<br></code>

Comment: I… have no idea what was going through my head when I wrote that. Fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the explicit use of `path.sep` is rarely necessary.

Comment: @DavidWolever I find it odd that `os.path.sep` is not mentioned in the [documentation for os.path](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html), nor in the [3.6-dev docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html). But [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.sep) is. However, [`os.path.supports_unicode_filenames`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.supports_unicode_filenames) (a constant/read-only/property) is mentioned. Perhaps a bug to be filed.

Answer (score 16):

I recommend you use `os.path.sep` for clarity, since it's a path separator, not an OS separator. If you `import os.path as path` you can call it `path.sep`, which is even better.

Comment: I find it odd that `os.path.sep` is not mentioned in the [documentation for os.path](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html), nor in the [3.6-dev docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html). But [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.sep) is. However, [`os.path.supports_unicode_filenames`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.supports_unicode_filenames) (a constant/read-only/property) is mentioned. Perhaps a bug to be filed.

Comment: I'd guess they leave it undocumented intentionally to encourage the use of `os.sep`. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Python 2.7, I suggest using `os.sep` (works) instead of `os.path.sep` (broken) as Jython on Windows has a bug returning a `"/"` slash instead of the required `"\"` backslash.

Answer (score 4):

The following examples could highlight the differences between os.path.join and os.path.sep.join.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join("output", "images", "saved")
'output/images/saved'
>>> os.path.sep.join(["output", "images", "saved"])
'output/images/saved'
```

I guess the os.path.sep.join is more robust and can be used w/o modifications for any os.

Comment: It almost seems like this is the actual purpose of the `os.path.sep` class.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the output, neither a reason why the secondo way should be more robust. As far as I know, also the first one is cross-system. In my opinion is always better to use the first, as it is a function which joins path, while the second join strings, but I believe it is just a conceptual difference. I would use path sep only when needed for string operations (e.g. to pass as argument to a function which wants a folder with final separator).

Comment: It's not *just* a conceptual difference. The outcome can very well be different, too. The first one can do anything that's required to join path components, including getting rid of components, the second one just joins strings with a separator, no matter what they contain. For a different outcome try `os.path.join('foo', '/bar')` vs. `os.path.sep.join(['foo', '/bar'])`. In almost all cases, the former is the one you want. Also, these days, you should be using `pathlib` instead, so path values are clearly distinct from strings and are processed accordingly in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

1. As mentioned in the python docs, both `os.path.sep` and `os.sep` return the same output.

> The character used by the operating system to separate pathname
> components. This is '/' for POSIX and '\' for Windows.

2. Both of them belongs to the same python class also.

   ```
   print(type(os.sep))
   print(type(os.path.sep))

   # Output
   <class 'str'>
   <class 'str'>
   ```
3. Both have them have the same documentation.

   ```
   print(os.path.sep.__doc__)
   print(os.sep.__doc__)

   # The outputs of both print statements are the same.
   ```

So, I think after Python2 where we mostly used `os.sep`, in Python3 only the consistency matters as far as their uses are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I have had os.path.sep return ':' in linux on python 2.7  which should be the result of os.pathsep (no second dot) but have never had the same issue with os.sep. Never did find out why but os.sep always solved the problem.