# Python os.path.dirname and os.path.sep in Java?

Tags: java, python

Python has os.path.dirname and os.path.sep.  How can I get these values in Java?

Comment: Look into [`System.getProperty(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a bit of googling on what [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) and [`os.path.sep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900520/which-one-should-i-use-os-sep-or-os-path-sep) actually are

`os.path.dirname(path)` would be `filePath.split(System.getProperty("path.separator"))[0]`

`os.path.sep` would be `System.getProperty("file.separator")`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not correct for `os.path.dirname`. `Paths.get(path).getParent()` is the Java equivalent.

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.path.dirname("/foo/bar/bax.txt")
Out[2]: '/foo/bar'

In [3]: os.path.dirname("/foo/bar")
Out[3]: '/foo'
```

```
jshell> import java.nio.file.Paths;

jshell> Paths.get("/foo/bar/baz.txt").getParent()
$2 ==> /foo/bar

jshell> Paths.get("/foo/bar").getParent()
$3 ==> /foo
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent--