# Why are os.path.join() on a list and os.path.sep.join() on a list not functionally identical?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

I'm working on a program that needs to split and rejoin some file paths, and I'm not sure why os.path.join(*list) and os.path.sep.join(list) produce different results when there is a drive letter present in the separated path.

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\choglan\\Desktop'

separatedPath = path.split(os.path.sep)
# ['C:', 'Users', 'choglan', 'Desktop']

path = os.path.sep.join(separatedPath)
# C:\\Users\\choglan\\Desktop
print(path)

path = os.path.join(*separatedPath)
# C:Users\\choglan\\Desktop
print(path)
```

Why does this happen? And should I just use os.path.sep.join(list) for my program even though os.path.join(*list) seems to be more commonly used?

Comment: This seems to be a Windows issue, as when I ran that exact block of code in Ubuntu it had no problem and both paths were identical.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900520/which-one-should-i-use-os-sep-or-os-path-sep and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431150/how-where-to-use-os-path-sep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.path.join` is not intended to be the inverse of `path.split(os.path.sep)`. If you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), you'll find a description of a much more complicated process than just sticking `os.path.sep` between the arguments. The most relevant part is the following:

> On Windows... Note that since there is a current directory for each drive, `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents a path relative to the current directory on drive `C:` (`c:foo`), not `c:\foo`.

You should probably be using `pathlib.PurePath(path).parts` rather than `path.split(os.path.sep)`.

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.sep` isn't an independent object with its own methods, it's a string. So the `join` method on it just pastes together the strings with that character between them.

```
>>> type(os.path.sep)
<class 'str'>
```

You can use `join` from any string.

```
>>> '|'.join(separatedPath)
'C:|Users|choglan|Desktop'
```